# Advise needed for Static vs Dynamic linking

Tags: python, c++, dll, static-libraries

I have a Python code that needs to be able to execute a C++ code. I'm new to the idea of creating libraries but from what I have learned so far I need to know whether I need to use static or dynamic linking.

I have read up on the pros and cons of both but there is a lot of jargon thrown around that I do not understand yet and since I need to do this ASAP I was wondering if some light can be shed on this from somebody who can explain it simply to me.

So here's the situation. My C++ code generates some text files that have data. My Python code then uses those text files to plot the data. As a starter, I need to be able to run the C++ code directly from Python. Is DLL more suitable than SL? Or am I barking up   the completely wrong tree?

*Extra: is it possible to edit variables in my C++ code, compile it and execute it, all directly from Python?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your desired deployment. If you use dynamic linking will need to carefully manage the libraries (`.so`, `.dll`) on your path and ensure that the correct version is loaded. This can be helped if you include the version number in the filename, but then that has its own problems (security... displaying version numbers of your code is a bad idea).
Another benefit is that you can swap your library functionality without a re-compile as long as the interface does not change.

Statically linking is conceptually simpler and practically simpler. You only have to deploy one artefact (an `.exe` for example). I **recommend** you start with that until you need to move to the more complicated shared library setup.

Edit: I don't understand your "extra credit" question. What do you mean by "edit values"? If you mean can you modify variables that were declared in your C++ code, then yes you can as long as you use part of the public interface to do it.
BTW this advice is for the general decision. If you are linking from Python to C/C++ I think you need to use a shared library. Not sure as I haven't done it myself.

EDIT: To expand on "public interface". When you create a C++ library of whatever kind, you specify what functions are available to outside classes (look up how to to that). This is what I mean by public interface. Parts of your library are inaccessible but others (that you specify) are able to be called from client code (i.e. your python script). This allows you to modify the values that are stored in memory.

If you DO mean that you want to edit the actual C++ code from within your python I would suggest that you should re-design your application. You should be able to customise the run-time behaviour of your C++ library by providing the appropriate configuration.

If you give a solid example of what you mean by that we'll be able to give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did mean edit variables. What do you mean by "public interface"?

Comment: +1: I agree. I do not see any benefits if you link dynamically. IMHO statically linking will fit your needs as you only need to run a routine and then parse those outcomes... you are not specifically referring to functions inside your code which should be called from python (dyn. linking)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible!!

Try exploring subprocess module in python.

Following can be an example implementation of your scenario:

```
yourfile.cpp
#compilation
args = ['g++','-o','your_executable_name_with_path','yourfile.cpp_with_path']
your_compile = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,compilation_error = your_compile.communicate()
your_compile.wait()

#successful compilation then there will be execuatble
if not compilation_error:
    #execuation
    args = ['your_executable_name_with_path'] #command to run a an execuatble
    your_run = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    your_code_output,runtime_error = your_run.communicate()
    your_run.wait()
```

Further, you can tackle more cases and come up with an efficient design

Comment: `args = ['./executable_name']` should actually be `args = ['your_executable_name_with_path']`. Right? You cannot suddenly assume the executable in the current directory if you didn't assume it when you created the executable by compiling the code.

Comment: yes ./ will look for the file in the same directory. To run an executable a neet and safe trick is to use a sandbox method either in python or pereferably in C using exec. Thanks @Nawaz

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how the idea of linking comes into what you are asking, but it sounds to me like you want to use something like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which allows you to create wrappers around C++ functions (and many other languages) which you can then call directly from your Python code.

> Extra: is it possible to edit values in my C++ code, compile it and execute it directly from Python?

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to use Python to change your C++ code, then compile and execute it? If this is the case, you may want to look into [embedding the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) in your C++ program. This would mean doing things the other way around and having C++ run your Python script, instead of trying to do everything from Python.